# jQuery get class value from parent div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the value in the class from 'quickCost' while I click on the 'icon-remove-sign'. I can get all of the html using the jQuery below but I don't know how to get to the class 'quickCost' from there to abstract the value.

In this case I am looking to get the $33.33 dollar amount.  My jQuery code outputs only the html. I am sure I am close. Thanks for any tips.

```
<div class="quickItem">
    <i class="icon-remove-sign" id="1457494010"></i>1 CD<div class="quickCost">$33.33</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$( '.icon-remove-sign' ).click(function() {
    var theCost = $( $(this).parent() ).html();
    console.log(theCost); // Outputs all html in parent div 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/):

```js
$('.icon-remove-sign').click(function() {
  var theCost = $(this).next('div.quickCost').text();
  console.log(theCost); // Outputs $33.33 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quickItem">
  <i class="icon-remove-sign" id="1457494010">x</i>1 CD
  <div class="quickCost">$33.33</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing. I will mark this answer correct in 10 minutes. It says I have to wait that long. :) Your fast. Thanks so much j08691.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `.parent()`

```
$('.icon-remove-sign').click(function() {
  var theCost = $(this).parent().find('.quickCost').text();
  console.log(theCost); // Outputs the text in .quickCost
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qLjuos62/